# Unable to install uwsgi on Mac OS High Sierra using pip3

Tags: python, macos, uwsgi

Whenever I try to install uwsgi on my Mac OS High Sierra it always exits with the following error code.

```
[thread 1][clang] core/xmlconf.o
[thread 2][clang] core/dot_h.o
[thread 3][clang] core/config_py.o
*** uWSGI compiling embedded plugins ***
[thread 0][clang] plugins/python/python_plugin.o
core/xmlconf.c:9:10: fatal error: 'libxml/parser.h' file not found
#include <libxml/parser.h>
1 error generated.
```

I have libxml installed, and other dependencies installed as well. I am using python 3.6, and this error came when I was using python 3.5 as well.

Comment: I thought so as well, I tried the solution in that answer, didn't work at all.

Comment: `$ locate parser.h`?